# Unable to load _dash-layout and _dash-dependencies from dash app running behind Nginx

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I am serving dash content inside a Flask app which uses blueprint for registering the routes.
App setup:

1. Dash is initialised with `route_pathname_prefix=/dashapp/`

```
dash_app = dash.Dash(
        server=server,
        routes_pathname_prefix='/dashapp/',
    )

dash_app.css.config.serve_locally = True
dash_app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
```

2. Registered dash app with Flask server
3. Used UWSGI to serve Flask app inside a docker container

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = </path/to/app.py>
callable = app
http = 0.0.0.0:8080
processes = 4
threads = 2
master = true
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

Upto this point everything was working fine locally. Once I added Nginx proxy, I got the below issue

Issue:
urls for `_dash-layout` and `_dash-dependencies` are missing the revers proxy uri. For example, I am serving my flask app at `www.example.com/app/`. But, on the browser, I saw that requests for `_dash-layout` and `_dash-dependencies` are coming at `www.example.com/dashpp/_dash-layout` instead of `www.example.com/app/dashpp/_dash-layout`.

I read the following forum [discussion](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-error-loading-layout/8139/5) and tried applying the solution, and got this error,
`requests_pathname_prefix` needs to start with '/'`

This is my Nginx config,

```
location /app/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:<port>;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:<port> http://example.com/app/;
    proxy_set_header Accept Encoding "";
    sub_filter_types *;
    sub_filter 'href="/' 'href="/app/';
    sub_filter 'src="/' 'src="/app/';
    sub_filter_once off;
}
```

Anyone has pointers to what is missing. I am new to dash. So, if I missed adding any information please let me know, I will be happy to give additional details

Thanks

PS: I added the same question in dash [forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/unable-to-load-dash-layout-and-dash-dependencies/53810?u=kanishka). Posting it here for better reach.

Edit:

To add additional context, I found out that url for `_dash-component-suites` is generated as expected `www.example.com/app/dashpp/_dash-component-suites`. I went through the dash source code to understand how urls are generated. Both, `_dash-component-suites` and `_dash-layout` are prefixed with `routes_pathname_prefix`. Line 428 to 448 of dash.py in version 1.14.0 has the code for building urls.

This is confusing!!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by removing `sub_filter` directive from nginx conf and updating url_prefixes in flask app. The steps I took are posted on [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/unable-to-load-dash-layout-and-dash-dependencies-from-dash-app-running-behind-nginx/53810/9?u=kanishka) dash forum